# Unable to compile pantheios 1.0.0-beta216 with stlsoft-1.9.124 on windows 7 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, pantheios

I'm having trouble compiling pantheios 1.0.0-beta2016 with stlsoft-1.9.124 on windows 7 64bit. The first error I had was

```
D:\Libraries\stlsoft-1.9.124\include\winstl/winstl.h(257) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling with WIN64 defined and _WIN64 not defined. Are you using the wrong makefile?
```

I got rid of the error by changing line 625 of the makefile to :

```
OS_DEFS             =   -DWIN64 -D_WIN64
```

Which generated this new error :

```
    cl    -nologo -c -W4 -WX  -O1 -MTd -D_DEBUG -Zi -Fd.\util.bailout.mt.debug.pdb    -DWIN64 -D_WIN64   -DSHWILD_QUALITY_NO_USE_XCOVER -DPANTHEIOS_NO_AUTO_INIT    -I..\..\include      -I"D:/Libraries/stlsoft-1.9.124\include"   -Fo.\util.bailout.mt.debug.obj ..\..\src\util\bailout.c
bailout.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(180) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(180) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'UINT_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(190) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'INT_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(255) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'INT_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(265) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'UINT_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(275) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(285) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(299) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared\basetsd.h(308) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG_PTR' to 'void *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(5842) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'PVOID *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(5843) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'PVOID'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(8691) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG64' to 'PVOID'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(8702) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG64' to 'PVOID'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(8713) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG64' to 'PVOID'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(19653) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG_PTR' to '_ACTIVATION_CONTEXT *'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um\winnt.h(19832) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to '_TEB *'
..\..\src\util\bailout.c(573) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'LONG_PTR' to 'HANDLE'
..\..\src\util\bailout.c(695) : warning C4305: 'type cast' : truncation from 'ULONG_PTR' to 'HKEY'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I then changed lines 657 and 670 to remove the -WX compiler option.

I still get these warnings but now it continues compiling (generating these warnings over and over again...) until :

```
    cl    -nologo -c -W4 -wd4800 -wd4996     -EHsc -GR -MTd -D_DEBUG -Zi -Fd.\util.be_context.mt.debug.pdb    -DWIN64 -D_WIN64   -DSHWILD_QUALITY_NO_USE_XCOVER -DPANTHEIOS_NO_AUTO_INIT    -I..\..\include      -I"D:/Libraries/stlsoft-1.9.124\include"   -Fo.\util.be_context.mt.debug.obj ..\..\src\util\be.context.cpp
be.context.cpp
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(494) : error C2371: 'size_t' : redefinition; different basic types predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(19) : see declaration of 'size_t'
D:\Libraries\pantheios-1.0.1-beta216\include\pantheios/internal/slice.hpp(110) : error C3861: 'size_t': identifier not found
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(282) : error C2338: This code is for 64-bit size_t.
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(283) : warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'unsigned __int64' to 'const size_t'
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(283) : warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(284) : warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'unsigned __int64' to 'const size_t'
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(284) : warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(300) : error C2338: This code is for 64-bit size_t.
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstddef(301) : warning C4293: '>>' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xutility(2906) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'ptrdiff_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
..\..\src\util\be.context.cpp(386) : error C3861: 'size_t': identifier not found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I am lost as to what to do...

To sum up my configuration :

- Windows 7 64bit, compiling with the makefile in \pantheios-1.0.1-beta216\build\vc12.x64\makefile
- Visual Studio 12 (2013)
- pantheios 1.0.0-beta216
- stlsoft-1.9.124 (with STLSOFT correctly defined)
- nmake to compile with prior execution of vcvarsall.bat

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found out that the cl compiler called was in fact compiling for x86. To tell cl to compile for 64bit platforms, I had to call vcvarsall.bat with the 'x64' option and it now compiles correctly with the original makefile!

Cheers!